# global variable error using Manager in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyquery

Here is my code, the key point is to share the `tweets`variable in multiprocessing:

```
import urllib,urllib2,json,re,datetime,sys,cookielib
from .. import models
from pyquery import PyQuery
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool, Queue, Manager
import os, time, random

def crawl_and_write(q,tweets):
    tweets = tweets
    for tweetHTML in tweets:

        tweetPQ = PyQuery(tweetHTML)
        tweet = models.Tweet()

        usernameTweet = tweetPQ("span:first.username.u-dir b").text();
        txt = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", tweetPQ("p.js-tweet-text").text().replace('# ', '#').replace('@ ', '@'));
        retweets = int(tweetPQ("span.ProfileTweet-action--retweet span.ProfileTweet-actionCount").attr(
            "data-tweet-stat-count").replace(",", ""));
        favorites = int(tweetPQ("span.ProfileTweet-action--favorite span.ProfileTweet-actionCount").attr(
            "data-tweet-stat-count").replace(",", ""));
        dateSec = int(tweetPQ("small.time span.js-short-timestamp").attr("data-time"));
        id = tweetPQ.attr("data-tweet-id");
        permalink = tweetPQ.attr("data-permalink-path");

        geo = ''
        geoSpan = tweetPQ('span.Tweet-geo')
        if len(geoSpan) > 0:
            geo = geoSpan.attr('title')

        tweet.id = id
        tweet.permalink = 'https://twitter.com' + permalink
        tweet.username = usernameTweet
        tweet.text = txt
        tweet.date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dateSec)
        tweet.retweets = retweets
        tweet.favorites = favorites
        tweet.mentions = " ".join(re.compile('(@\\w*)').findall(tweet.text))
        tweet.hashtags = " ".join(re.compile('(#\\w*)').findall(tweet.text))
        tweet.geo = geo

        # add tweet into queue
        q.put(tweet)

def read_result(q):
    while True:
        # get value from the queue
        tweet = q.get(True)
        results.append(tweet)
        resultsAux.append(tweet)

        if receiveBuffer and len(resultsAux) >= bufferLength:
            receiveBuffer(resultsAux)
            length += len(resultsAux)
            # tell the finish percerntage of the process
            percent = length / float(tweetCriteria.maxTweets) * 100
            resultsAux = []
            print '%.2f %% of tweets required was finished, we have %s tweets now' % (percent, length)

        if tweetCriteria.maxTweets > 0 and len(results) >= tweetCriteria.maxTweets:
            active = False

def getTweets(tweetCriteria, receiveBuffer=None, bufferLength=100, proxy=None):
    refreshCursor = ''

    length = 0
    results = []
    resultsAux = []
    cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()

    if hasattr(tweetCriteria, 'username') and (tweetCriteria.username.startswith("\'") or tweetCriteria.username.startswith("\"")) and (tweetCriteria.username.endswith("\'") or tweetCriteria.username.endswith("\"")):
        tweetCriteria.username = tweetCriteria.username[1:-1]

    active = True
    manager = Manager()


    while active:
        json = TweetManager.getJsonReponse(tweetCriteria, refreshCursor, cookieJar, proxy)
        if len(json['items_html'].strip()) == 0:
            break

        refreshCursor = json['min_position']            

        tweets = PyQuery(json['items_html'])('div.js-stream-tweet')
        tweets = manager(tweets)

        if len(tweets) == 0:
            break

        pw = Process(target = crawl_and_write, args=(q,tweets))
        pr = Process(target = read_result, args=(q,))
        # start pw
        pw.start()
        # start pr
        pr.start()
        # wait for the pw end
        pw.join()
```

However, the error was shown in the code `tweets = manager(tweets)` as `Pickle.PicklingError:Can't pickle<class 'pyquery.pyquery.NoDefault'>:attribute lookup pyqery.pyquery.NoDefault failed`.

I guess it is because of the pyquery type but still have no idea how to fix it?

Any thoughs would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Manager use pickle to serialize object into binary stream, and then transform it through network. So as not every object can be serialized, may be you cannot fix this problem.

Comment: Thx. Do you think there is another way to share the `tweets` variable?

Comment: @exteralvictor As far as I think, you can share all the data you need to recreate a `tweets` in a collection(e.g. `dict` or `list`), and then recreate it in process.

Comment: Thx, but could you maybe give me an example?